# onClick not showing div

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

My jquery is not showing the div that I want it to at http://jsfiddle.net/jspence29/a3BQR/1/

I want the large divs to appear when you click on the button and dissapear when you click again, but it just isn't appearing. Thanks

Also, what is more rcommended using the css changing jquery or just this show and hide query?

```
$(".first1").onClick(
  function () {
    $('#suitsyou').show();
  },
  function () 
    $('#suitsyou').hide();
  });
```

or something like

```
$("div").click(function () {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  $("#result").html("That div is <span style='color:" +
                     color + ";'>" + color + "</span>.");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(".first1").on('click', 
  function () {
    $('#suitsyou').toggle();
  });
$(".last1").on('click', 
  function () {
      $('#dealsandoffers').toggle() 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').hide()
$('li.first1').click(function(){
    $('div').hide()
   $('#suitsyou').slideToggle();
});
$('li.last1').click(function(){
   $('div').hide()
   $('#dealsandoffers').slideToggle();
});    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid, which you'd know if you'd looked at your browser's developer tools (you'll have errors in the console).

There's no `onclick()` function in jQuery, it's simply called `.click()` and it takes a *single* function to execute when that event is triggered. You can't pass two functions to be executed on alternate clicks, though jQuery does provide a function for that: [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (not to be confused with the function that toggles the visibility of a set of elements)

Usage:

```
$(".first1").toggle(
    function () {
        $('#suitsyou').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('#suitsyou').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a large number of errors that I have corrected here: http://jsfiddle.net/a3BQR/4/  -- note that using `.toggle` in this way has been removed in jQuery 1.9.  I just did it here for convenience.

1. `.onClick` is not a function
2. You are missing the open parentheses after `function ()` for the second function.
3. You didn't pick jQuery as your framework in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('li.first1').click(function(){
   $('#suitsyou').toggle();
  });
});
```

And hide the div in your html

```
<div id="suitsyou" style='display:none'>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6Uvx/